# Serializing/deserializing objects with mixins

Tags: c++, templates, serialization, boost-serialization

Is there a way to deal with mixins when writing/reading objects? I'm using Boost Serialization, but this is a fairly generic question. Say I have properties attached via mixins as follows:

```
struct Point {
    double x,y;
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin1 : public Base {
public:
    double someProperty;
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin2 : public Base {
public:
    double otherProperty;
};

int main() {
    typedef MyMixin2<MyMixin1<PointTypeA> > Mixed12;
    Mixed12 mixed12;

    serialize(mixed12, "someFile.txt");

    Mixed12 mixed12Read = deserialize("someFile.txt");

    return 0;
}

void serialize(Mixed12 object, string filename)
{
    Archive archive(filename);
    WriteIfAvailable(archive, object, someProperty);
    WriteIfAvailable(archive, object, otherProperty);
}

template <typename TObject>
TObject deserialize(string filename)
{
    // How does this function know which data is present and in which order?
    Archive archive(filename);

    TSomeProperty someProperty;
    archive >> someProperty; // We aren't sure if serialize() wrote 'someProperty' first, second, or at all
    AssignIfAvailable(object, someProperty, someProperty);

    TOtherProperty otherProperty;
    archive >> otherProperty; // We aren't sure if serialize() wrote 'otherProperty' first, second, or at all
    AssignIfAvailable(object, otherProperty, otherProperty);
}
```

In `serialize()`, I use SFINAE to write all of the properties that are available to the archive, but then in `deserialize()`, how would I know which order the properties were written in to deserialize them? I thought of writing a "header" at the beginning that indicates which properties were written and in which order, but then if I have a `std::vector<Mixed12>` that approach would require the header to be written for each point, which seems excessive. I also though of handling the `std::vector` case explicitly (or more generally, probably a MyClass that happens to contain a Mixin12 or a collection of Mixin12) and write a header for the outer object, but this object should rely on using the serialization function of its contents, which would not be aware of the existence of this header.

The best outcome is that we can write one type (e.g. Mixed12) to a file, then read it into a "compatible" object (e.g. Mixed21).

Answer (score 0):

Please find below a full working example. Text archive is used for ease of inspection - you can see that there's no redundant data stored in the output for vectors. The solution is based on best practice approach to derived classes serialization recommended by `boost::serialization` docs. The third part demonstrates how to serialize a vector of base class pointers (e.g. `Point`) to derived classes (e.g. `Mixed12` and `Mixed21`). Please notice that still no  redundancy is present in the archive, thanks to usage of class GUIDs (you can make them shorter if want to save space). Also you can see how the fact that pointers to same objects are stored repetitively - boost only stores indices later on.

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

namespace ser=boost::serialization;
namespace arch=boost::archive;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Point {
    double x,y;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & x;
        ar & y;
    }
    virtual ~Point() {};
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin1 : public Base {
    friend class ser::access;
public:
    double someProperty;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & ser::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & someProperty;
    }
    virtual ~MyMixin1() {}
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin2 : public Base {
public:
    double otherProperty;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & ser::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & otherProperty;
    }
    virtual ~MyMixin2() {}
};

typedef MyMixin2<MyMixin1<Point> > Mixed12;
typedef MyMixin1<MyMixin2<Point> > Mixed21;


BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Mixed12, "Mixed12")
BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(Mixed21, "Mixed21")

int main() {

    Mixed12 mixed12;
    Mixed21 mixed21;

    mixed12.someProperty = 5;
    mixed12.otherProperty = 10;
    mixed12.x = 2;
    mixed12.y = 3;

    mixed21.someProperty = 6;
    mixed21.otherProperty = 7;
    mixed21.x = 9;
    mixed21.y = 8;

    cout << "Testing simple serialization..." << endl;
    {
        std::ofstream f("someFile.txt");
        arch::text_oarchive ar(f);    
        ar << mixed12;
        ar << mixed21;
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing simple deserialization..." << endl;
    {
        Mixed12 mixed12_deser;
        Mixed21 mixed21_deser;

        std::ifstream f("someFile.txt");
        arch::text_iarchive ar(f);
        ar >> mixed12_deser;
        ar >> mixed21_deser;

        cout << mixed12_deser.someProperty << " " << mixed12_deser.otherProperty
            << " " << mixed12_deser.x << " " << mixed12_deser.y << endl;

        assert(mixed12.someProperty == mixed12_deser.someProperty &&
            mixed12.otherProperty == mixed12_deser.otherProperty &&
            mixed12.x == mixed12_deser.x &&
            mixed12.y == mixed12_deser.y);

        assert(mixed21.someProperty == mixed21_deser.someProperty &&
            mixed21.otherProperty == mixed21_deser.otherProperty &&
            mixed21.x == mixed21_deser.x &&
            mixed21.y == mixed21_deser.y);
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing vector serialization..." << endl;
    {
        std::vector<Mixed12> v12;
        std::vector<Mixed21> v21;
        std::ofstream f("vectorFile.txt");
        arch::text_oarchive ar(f);

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) v12.push_back(mixed12);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) v21.push_back(mixed21);

        ar << v12;
        ar << v21;
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing vector deserialization..." << endl;
    {
        std::vector<Mixed12> v12;
        std::vector<Mixed21> v21;
        std::ifstream f("vectorFile.txt");
        arch::text_iarchive ar(f);

        ar >> v12;
        ar >> v21;

        for (std::vector<Mixed12>::const_iterator it = v12.begin(); it != v12.end(); it++)
            assert(mixed12.someProperty == it->someProperty &&
            mixed12.otherProperty == it->otherProperty &&
            mixed12.x == it->x &&
            mixed12.y == it->y);

        for (std::vector<Mixed21>::const_iterator it = v21.begin(); it != v21.end(); it++)
            assert(mixed21.someProperty == it->someProperty &&
            mixed21.otherProperty == it->otherProperty &&
            mixed21.x == it->x &&
            mixed21.y == it->y);

    }
    cout << "OK!" << endl;

    cout << "Testing base class serialization..." << endl;
    {
        std::vector<Point*> v;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                v.push_back(&mixed12);
            else
                v.push_back(&mixed21);

        std::ofstream f("basePtrFile.txt");
        arch::text_oarchive ar(f);

        ar << v;
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing base class deserialization..." << endl;
    {
        std::vector<Point*> v;
        std::ifstream f("basePtrFile.txt");
        arch::text_iarchive ar(f);
        ar >> v;
        assert(v.size() == 16);
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                assert(dynamic_cast<Mixed12*>(v[i]) != 0);
                assert(dynamic_cast<Mixed21*>(v[i]) == 0);
            } else {
                assert(dynamic_cast<Mixed21*>(v[i]) != 0);
                assert(dynamic_cast<Mixed12*>(v[i]) == 0);
            }
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this method requires that the exact same type that was used to serialize the object is used to deserialize it. I guess my question was (apparently unclearly, sorry!) getting at if there is a way to ser/deserialize objects into different types that actually have the same underlying properties. I.e. a Mixed12 can be copied to a Mixed21 by copying each potential property using SFINAE (e.g. `if(hasProperty(object, someProperty)...copy value...`. But if you serialize a Mixed12 and then deserialize it to a Mixed21, the values will be read out of order. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Also, this was a simple case where we had only 2 mixins and 2 "levels". Sometimes a user of my library may create a `A<D<B<C<Point>>>>`. They then need to call `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` on that type before this infrastructure will work. Is there a way to build something into the mixins themselves so this would be more automatic?

Comment: Hmm so they would serialize as A<B<C<D<Point> > > > but deserialize to D<B<C<A<Point> > > > ? This can work if you deserialize simply to Point*. It will not only read fields correctly but instantiate the right class for you. Or do you mean serializing A<B<C> > > and deserializing to D<E<F> > > and common base class is absolutely prohibited? As long as there's a common base you can read to the base pointer and it will not only get it right but instantiate the correct type. The latter admittedly has to be introduced by BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID - not a problem for programmers. Who's your audience?

Comment: Also once you deserialize to common base pointer you can use dynamic_cast to identify which properties are available and therefore have your SFINAE pattern.

Comment: "serialize as `A<B<C<D<Point> > > >` but deserialize to `D<B<C<A<Point> > > >`", yep, that'd be ideal. A common base class can be a requirement.

Comment: I am using the MemberDetector pattern to do the SFINAE (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Member_Detector) . This allows me to copy any properties that are available in both types A and B from an object of A into an object of B. I guess I am looking to do the same thing, but through a file (ser/deserialization).

Comment: A dynamic_cast will try to match the type exactly, no? I.e. you can't create a Mixed12 as a Point* and then successfully dynamic_cast to Mixed21, right?

Comment: Ah ok it starts making more sense now, as the Member Detector is a compile-time pattern it doesn't work in runtime, so basically you can't deserialize via the base class. That's a serious limitation you introduced with that pattern - why do you need it? Wouldn't just using dynamic_cast be much easier?

Comment: You can't cast to Mixed21 but you can cast to MyMixin1 and MyMixin2 separately - isn't this good enough? E.g. `if (dynamic_cast<MyMixin1*>(base)) ((MyMixin1*) base) -> I_can_access_MyMixin1_property = 5;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104194/discussion-between-david-doria-and-algoholic).

Comment: You can check out my new answer, it solves the GUID issues.

Answer (score 0):

The mixins aren't a problem. Create `serialize` for each type, and within `serialize` forward & make sure the base gets a shot at writing its data as well. The properties will be written & read in a deterministic fashion, there's no extra data needed. For your sample code:

```
#include "boost/serialization/serialization.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp"
#include "boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp"
#include <fstream>
struct Point {
    double x, y;
    template< typename TArch >
    void serialize(TArch& a_Archive, const unsigned int a_Version )
    {
        a_Archive & x & y;
    }
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin1 : public Base {
public:
    template< typename TArch >
    void serialize(TArch& a_Archive, const unsigned int a_Version )
    {
        a_Archive & someProperty;
        boost::serialization::serialize(a_Archive, static_cast<Base&>(*this), a_Version);
    }
    double someProperty;
};

template<class Base>
class MyMixin2 : public Base {
public:
    template< typename TArch >
    void serialize(TArch& a_Archive, const unsigned int a_Version)
    {
        a_Archive & otherProperty;
        boost::serialization::serialize(a_Archive, static_cast<Base&>(*this), a_Version);
    }
    double otherProperty;
};

int main() {
    typedef MyMixin2<MyMixin1<Point> > Mixed12;
    Mixed12 mixed12;

    {
        std::ofstream ifs("someFile.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oArch(ifs);
        oArch << mixed12;
    }
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("someFile.txt");
        boost::archive::text_iarchive iArch(ifs);
        iArch >> mixed12;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you're serializing pointers to base types an ID is needed to make sure that the `serialize` of the most derived type is called during save / load. There's a section in the manual for `boost::serialize` called `Pointers to Objects of Derived Classes`. Mixin or not doesn't really change anything however.

Comment: After discussion with ALGOholic it was pointed out that I wasn't clear about the goal of reading/writing from "compatible" types, not just exactly the same type. I have added a note about this to the end of the question.

Comment: I think you have a design problem reading the other thread. `A<B<C<Point> > >` will have a different layout than `C<B<A<Point> > >` but have the same members. To support saving one & reading into the other would require that you write meta data for each part of the chain in order to make sure everything ends up at the correct location. The tricky part will be deserialization. When reading `B` in `B<C<...> >` it isn't the same as `B<A<...> >`, its data may be at a different offset. So you'll need to support all the permutations at every level which will create a ton of bloat.

Answer (score 0):

This is another possibility using custom serializer, it satisfies your requirement of writing Mixed12 and reading Mixed21 and so on and still uses layout specifications sparingly (only when new layout is serialized it is embedded into the file, otherwise indexing is used). Interestingly you can even have classes using different types for same field names, as long as you deserialize to correct class it will work perfectly because just the order of fields needs to be known. Disclaimer: it's a proof of concept, there are still caveats to address (e.g. what if a field is not consumed, the layout should contain field length so that it can be skipped and so on - it's just some work you'll have to do).

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
namespace ser=boost::serialization;
using boost::archive::text_iarchive;
using boost::archive::text_oarchive;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


typedef vector<string> FieldNames;


struct Serializer {

    ofstream f;
    text_oarchive ar;
    vector<vector<string> > layouts;

    Serializer(const char *fname): ar(f), f(fname) {
    }

    template <class Class>
    Serializer& operator<<(Class &obj) {

        vector<string> names;
        obj.fieldNames(names);
        unsigned int i;
        for (i = 0; i < layouts.size(); i++)
            if(layouts[i] == names) break;
        if (i == layouts.size()) {
            layouts.push_back(names);
            unsigned int id(0x80000000 | i);
            ar << id;
            ar << names;
            // cout << "New layout: " << i << endl;
        } else {
            // cout << "Reusing layout: " << i << endl;
            ar << i;
        }
        obj.serialize(ar, 0);


        return *this;
    }
};

struct Deserializer {

    ifstream f;
    text_iarchive ar;
    vector<vector<string> > layouts;

    Deserializer (const char *fname): ar(f), f(fname) {
    }

    template <class Class>
    Deserializer& operator>>(Class &obj) {

        unsigned int i;
        ar >> i;
        vector<string> names;
        if (0x80000000 & i) {
            ar >> names;
            // cout << "Reading names..." << endl;
            layouts.push_back(names);
        } else {
            names = layouts[i];
        }


        for (i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            // cout << "Calling deserialize for name:" << names[i] << endl;
            obj.deserialize(ar, names[i]);
        }


        return *this;
    }
};

struct Point {
    int x, y;

    void fieldNames(FieldNames &names) {
        names.push_back("x");
        names.push_back("y");
    }

    void serialize(text_oarchive &ar, unsigned int ver) {
        ar << x;
        ar << y;
    }

    void deserialize(text_iarchive &ar, string &name) {
        // cout << "Point::deserialize() name:" << name << endl;
        if (name == "x") ar >> x;
        if (name == "y") ar >> y;
    }

};

template<class Base>
struct Mixin1: public Base {
    int a;

    void fieldNames(FieldNames &names) {
        Base::fieldNames(names);
        names.push_back("a");
    }

    void serialize(text_oarchive &ar, unsigned int ver) {
        Base::serialize(ar, ver);
        ar << a;
    }

    void deserialize(text_iarchive &ar, string &name) {
        Base::deserialize(ar, name);
        if (name == "a") ar >> a;
    }
};

template<class Base>
struct Mixin2: public Base {
    int b;

    void fieldNames(FieldNames &names) {
        Base::fieldNames(names);
        names.push_back("b");
    }

    void serialize(text_oarchive &ar, unsigned int ver) {
        Base::serialize(ar, ver);
        ar << b;
    }

    void deserialize(text_iarchive &ar, string &name) {
        Base::deserialize(ar, name);
        if (name == "b") ar >> b;
    }
};

typedef Mixin1<Mixin2<Point> > Mixed12;
typedef Mixin2<Mixin1<Point> > Mixed21;

int main() {
    cout << "Testing serialization" << endl;
    {
        Serializer ser("ser2_test.txt");
        Mixed12 m12;
        Mixed21 m21;
        m12.x = 1; m12.y = 2; m12.a = 3; m12.b = 4;        
        m21.x = 5; m21.y = 6; m21.a = 7; m21.b = 8;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            ser << m12;
            ser << m21;
        }
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing deserialization to Mixed12" << endl;
    {
        Deserializer des("ser2_test.txt");
        Mixed12 m12;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            des >> m12;
            // cout << "m12: " << m12.x << " " << m12.y << " " << m12.a << " " << m12.b << endl;
            assert(m12.x == 1 && m12.y == 2 && m12.a == 3 && m12.b == 4);
            des >> m12;
            assert(m12.x == 5 && m12.y == 6 && m12.a == 7 && m12.b == 8);
        }
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;

    cout << "Testing deserialization to Mixed21" << endl;
    {
        Deserializer des("ser2_test.txt");
        Mixed21 m21;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            des >> m21;
            assert(m21.x == 1 && m21.y == 2 && m21.a == 3 && m21.b == 4);
            des >> m21;
            assert(m21.x == 5 && m21.y == 6 && m21.a == 7 && m21.b == 8);
        }
    }
    cout << "OK" << endl;
}
```